# Updating data in STL vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have the vector below

```
vector<CarRecord> FileRecords;
```

`CarRecord` is a structure that looks like this:

```
typedef struct 
{   
    char carName[14];
    eStatus carStatus;
    eCarType carType;
} CarRecord;
```

I have a class that works with this vector, and I met some problems: I don't know how to write the `Update(CarRecord *Rec, eStatus NewStatus);` function.

I found a question here that is answered like so:

```
vector[index] = newValue;
```

but I don't know how to find my specific item.

EDIT:

My vector currently looks like this for example:

```
Name    Type Status
Nissan  4    1
Peugeot 3    1
```

At the status, `1` us for `Available`, `0` is for `Unavailable`.

What I need? I need my function to find the record with name `Peugeot` and change the type to the value of my `NewType` parameter.

Comment: If you are not specifically bothered to have a contiguous store then just use std::set<CarRecord, CarRecordComparator>, assuming CarRecordComparator is the record comparison logic. Else use std::find as suggested in one of answers.

Answer (score 0):

To find a specific record can you use something like

```
std::vector<CarRecord>::iterator iter;
iter = std::find(FileRecords.begin(), FileRecords.end(), recordToFind);
```

then *iter should point to the record you wanted to find? I'm a noob so sorry if this is wrong

Comment: instead of `std::vector<CarRecord>::iterator` is it ok to use `this->FileRecords::iterator iter`?

Comment: I see that you are newbie, I will not downvote. I will try it in a few moments and come back with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using vector here? This looks much more suitable for a map.

Aside: You code looks like C plus or minus, not C++. Get rid of that typedef, change that `char[14]` to `std::string`.

With that change from `char[14]` to `std::string`, `std::map<std::string, CarRecord>` looks like a perfect fit to your problem. The index to the map is the name of the car rather than some integer.

Comment: I would like us to continue on a chat room, because my problem is more specific and it creates more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Quote :

To find a specific record can you use something like

```
std::vector<CarRecord>::iterator iter;
iter = std::find(FileRecords.begin(), FileRecords.end(), recordToFind);
```

End quote from "fiveoak".

1. what fiveoak says is right, you can use std::find to find a specific record as shown above.
2. to use std::find, you also need to define your own equal operator, i.e. override the equal operator

Change your CarRecord as this  in a header file

```
    struct CarRecord 
    {   
        char carName[14];
        eStatus carStatus;
        eCarType carType;
        bool operator ==(CarRecord const& other) const;

    } ;
```

// put this in another cpp file
        #include "your_car_record_header.h"
        #include

```
    bool CarRecord::operator ==(CarRecord const& other);
   { 
        return std::strcmp(carName, other.carName) == 0;
   }
```

I also agree with what David Hammen said that it is better to use std::string instead of char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```
bool Update(char *car, eCarType newType)
{

auto it = std::find_if(FileRecords.begin(),
                  FileRecords.end(),
                  [=](const CarRecord& c ){
                  return strstr(c.carName,car) != '\0';
                  }
                  );

if(it != FileRecords.end())
   {
      it->carType = newType;  
      return true;
   }

  return false;
}
```